# Barrier file not found (C++ Makefile)

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, clang

I am trying to compile a project however the make command returns with the error

> fatal error: 'barrier' file not found

and after changing clang versions and changing my platform, nothing seems to help. Therefore I would like to ask for assistance regarding this issue.

Here is my makefile:

```html
CC = clang
CXX = clang++

CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -std=c18 -pthread
CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS) -stdlib=libc++ -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -std=c++20 -pthread

all: project

SRCS = main.cpp input.cpp output.cpp project.cpp

project: $(SRCS:%=%.o)
    $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o project


DEPDIR := .deps
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$<.d

COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
COMPILE.cpp = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c

%.c.o: %.c
%.c.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.c.d | $(DEPDIR)
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

%.cpp.o: %.cpp
%.cpp.o: %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.cpp.d | $(DEPDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(DEPDIR): ; @mkdir -p $@

DEPFILES := $(SRCS:%=$(DEPDIR)/%.d) $(DEPDIR)/client.c.d
$(DEPFILES):

include $(wildcard $(DEPFILES))
```

**EDIT**
The platform details:

clang --version output:

```
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

OS details:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Full error:

```
clang++ -MT project.cpp.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/project.cpp.d  -stdlib=libc++ -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -std=c++1z -pthread    -c -o project.cpp.o project.cpp
In file included from project.cpp:1:
./project.hpp:9:10: fatal error: 'barrier' file not found
#include <barrier>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'project.cpp.o' failed
make: *** [project.cpp.o] Error 1
```

**EDIT-2**
flag c++20 gives off error: invalid value 'c++20' in '-std=c++20'

Comment: Please give more context for the error - it is not even clear where that error comes from and which command exactly is producing it. At least show more of the build log. Even better, provide a complete [mre]. That is provide minimal code and minimal Makefile that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @kaylum I just added the OS details, clang version, full error log and makefile. Any cpp file with #include <barrier> causes the problem to occur

Comment: [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/barrier) says that header is only supported for C++20. Try adding `-std=c++20` to your build flags.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but if I change the flag I get "error: invalid value 'c++20' in '-std=c++20'" instead

Comment: The [clang docs](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) says: "*You can use Clang in C++20 mode with the -std=c++20 option (use -std=c++2a in Clang 9 and earlier).*". You are clang6 so `-std=c++2a` would apply I assume.

Comment: Yes you are right, I added that as an edit. -std=c++2a doesn't seem to solve the problem either though (barrier cannot be found)

Comment: Clang 6 is old, get the latest one. Since you're probably using GCC's standard library, you need a new GCC too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I moved to clang version 10 and gcc version 7.5 but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: @FioralbaAmaranta [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) says it was added in GCC 11 and Clang 11.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Verified in compiler explorer. 10 is a no go, but in 11 it works. Fioralba Amaranta: Do you need to stay with Ubuntu 18? 20.04 has been around for quite some time now and 22.04 was just released. You should find more up-to-date compilers in any of those.